# Azure storage monitoring from the web portal

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I'm trying to enable the monitoring tiles in my Azure Storage account, but for the life of me can't get it to work. It keeps coming up with the error"monitoring may not be enabled. Please turn on diagnostics".

I've tried ticking all the checkboxes under Settings->Diagnostics->Monitoring but nothing seems to work.

Is there a trick I'm missing?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cie/2015/02/12/monitoring-blade-in-the-new-portal-showing-monitoring-may-not-be-enabled-click-here-to-turn-on-diagnostic-for-the-azure-services/

Comment: Hi Stuartd, I did find that article earlier but it refers to a different service that have a storage account in order to work. This is with an actual storage account :-(

Comment: Do you have any other Storage accounts that you could try this with? Did you create this Storage Account via the old portal or new portal?

Comment: Hi There Mark C., I did try creating another Storage account in a different resource pool, and exactly the same behaviour. It is quite bizzar. I created the Storage Account via the new portal

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to monitor a Premium Azure Storage account?  I dont believe those can be monitored at this time, as monitored/analytical data for them is stored in Table Storage and Premium Storage accounts do not support Table Storage or Queue storage.